# Title changed programmatically is not put into breadcrumbs

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

I have 2 functions in template.php: The first attaches current page title to breadcrumbs; the second sets the title to 'Completion' when the user opens /scores/completion.

```
function lwt_breadcrumb($variables) {
    $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
    if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
        // Adding the title of the current page to the breadcrumb.
        $breadcrumb[] = drupal_get_title();

        // Provide a navigational heading to give context for breadcrumb links to
        // screen-reader users. Make the heading invisible with .element-invisible.
        $output = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('You are here') . '</h2>';

        $output .= '<div class="breadcrumb">' . implode(' » ', $breadcrumb) . '</div>';
        return $output;
    }
}

function lwt_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
      $path = drupal_get_path_alias();
      if ($path == 'scores/completion') {
            $vars['title'] = 'Completion';
      }
}
```

The breadcrumb is still scores. How do I fix it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is the page title changing?  I.e. is it JUST the breadcrumb that's broken, or is your preprocess not firing at all?

Comment: The page title is changing. Preprocess is firing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[drupal_get_title()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_title/7) gets the title from a PHP static variable, which is different from the variable `$variables['title']` passed to the template files.

Your template hook would work if it uses the following code.

```
function lwt_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias();
  if ($path == 'scores/completion') {
    // -1-
    $vars['title'] = t('Completion');
    drupal_set_title($vars['title']);
    // -1-
  }
}
```

What happens is the following:

- `lwt_preprocess_page()` is invoked, and (through [drupal_set_title()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7)) sets the static variable containing the value returned from `drupal_get_title()`.
- [template_process_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_process_page/7) is invoked, and it calls the theme function for the breadcrumbs; in your case that theme function is `lwt_breadcrumb()`, which calls `drupal_get_title()`, obtaining the same value you set in `lwt_preprocess_page()`.

In `lwt_preprocess_page()` you could also replace the code between `// -1-` with the following one.

```
    unset($vars['title']);
    drupal_set_title(t('Completion'));
```

The reason also this code works is that `template_process_page()` first checks if `$variables['title']` is set; if it is not set, it calls `drupal_get_title()`.

```
  if (!isset($variables['title'])) {
    $variables['title'] = drupal_get_title();
  }
```

#### References

- [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7), for the order in which theme template hooks are executed
- [drupal_static()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7), for understanding how the page title is stored in a static variable accessible to any function